# Push notifications from the app

Tags: ios, notifications

How could I push notifications FROM THE APP. I mean without needing to reach for a server to receive it. I mean sending one from the app, like the reminders or calendar app do

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/notifications/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Local Notification.

More difference between local and push notification check it [out here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1).

Tutorial on Local notification: http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/